# Excel VBA - copying sheet with charts to another workbook, error on close

Tags: excel, vba, charts, copy

I got stuck with this issue:

I am copying a number of sheets from several Excel workbooks into one specific workbook.
I use this code:

```
SourceWorkbook.SourceSheet.Cells.Copy DestinationWorkbook.DestinationSheet.Cells(1,1)
```

DestinationWorkbook being a Object with loaded Excel workbook.

Everything works fine until I ran into sheets with charts (chartobjects). Copying is fine, but I am unable to close DestinationWorkbook and I receive a error message about insufficient resources for the action (memory?).

I think it might be something with links (charts are linked to the original workbook).

I have tried to clear clipboard, change .Values, .XValues, .Names of all charts, break links (not sure it worked properly),  save the DestinationWorkbook, DoEvents, On Error Resume Next, etc. but it still doesnt work properly.

My last option is to delete the charts from SourceWorkbook and create them by myself but I would like to avoid it, as it will be much complicated as it may vary from sheet to sheet.

Hope anyone can help.

The whole code is complicated but the most important part is this:

```
Set SourceWorkbook = GetObject(Path)
SourceWorkbook.SourceSheet.Cells.Copy DestinationWorkbook.DestinationSheet.Cells(1,1)
SourceWorkbook .Close Savechanges:=False
Set SourceWorkbook = Nothing
```

Comment: Please email me the workbooks so I can take a look at them

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the entire sheet which may cause memory leek:

```
SourceWorkbook.SourceSheet.Cells.Copy DestinationWorkbook.DestinationSheet.Cells(1,1)
```

Try copying a specific range:

```
  SourceWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Range(SourceWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Cells(1, 1), _
  SourceWorkbook.Sheets(SourceSheet).Cells(100, 100)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(DestinationSheet).Cells(1, 1)
```